# .NET Core WebApp, multiple domains, changing SQL connection string based on hostname, can't inject httpcontext into DB Context.cs file

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service

I am using Azure .NET core WebApp, MVC, Entity Framework, scaffolded in an existing external MS SQL database.

I register the DB in the startup ConfigureServices like this:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer());
```

And it works fine so long as I set the connection string in the MyDbContext.cs OnConfiguring() method like this:

```cs
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=10.10.10.10;Database=MyDb;user id=username;password=password;");
        }
```

Then I can simply in a Controller say:

```cs
        private readonly MyDbContext _context;
        public HomeController()
        {
            _context = new MyDbContext();
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var item = _context.TableName.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id > 0);
        }
```

And this works fine - data flows in.

My problem is that I need to change the SQL connection string depending on what hostname is connecting. So, either in the startup ConfigureServices() I can pass the connection if I can establish the hostname being used, or in the DB's MyDbContext.cs file's OnConfiguring() method.

I can get the hostname only from the httpcontext, and that isn't available to query in the startup so far as I can tell?

If I try and inject it into the context.cs DB file, like this:

```cs
    public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public MyDbContext()
        {
        }

        public MyDbContext(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;         // For context/url
        }

        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
            : base(options)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;         // For context/url
        }
```

Then the startup ConfigureServices line services.AddDbContext can't pass the httpcontext (it doesn't exist at that point?) none of the constructor methods match - I can't inject the IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor into the DB context method no matter how I try!

```cs
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("some-connection-string")); // Doesn't pass httpcontext
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>()); // Doesn't pass httpcontext
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(is there way to pass it?);
```

It doesn't seem to work like injecting it into Controllers, which does work fine as there's no constructor there...

Any ideas on how I can find the hostname and change the SQL connection string given this setup?

For various reasons this needs to be a single WebApp that multiple domains use by the way.

### edit

After a sleepless night I woke up and decided to simply connect to all (three) databases I need and then decide which context to use in the controller, as I have the httpcontext there to decide what host is connecting. It's not ideal, but this is a low overhead WebApp so I'm happy enough to go with it like that. I think perhaps there is/was a solution out there though...

Comment: Are you saying that if you inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into your `DbContext`, you get an exception on the `services.AddDbContext` line? It sure feels like that should be the way to go.

Comment: I can't access the IHttpContextAccessor in the DbContext - it's simply not there. I suppose I can't pass it in when I create the DbContext in startup (or I don't know how to!). i.e. services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>()); // Doesn't pass httpcontext - this doesn't pass the context - how can it be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the approach I've been using for multi-tenant solutions (where clients have their own database).

Create your context with this constructor signature (no need for `OnConfiguring`):

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
        : base(options) { }
}
```

In your Startup, you need to register your context and we can now add a resolver to get the correct connection settings:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();

// This registers DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> which will be called when a new
// instance of MyDbContext is created. You could set breakpoints in this method.
services.AddScoped(sp => 
{
    var context = sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;

    // your logic to determine connection string or EF provider
    // ...

    var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
    builder.UseSqlServer("connection string");

    return builder.Options;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't work for me unless I can get the httpcontext in startup - as that's how I decide on which string to use - it depends on the domain accessing the WebApp. It seems impossible to establish this in startup, so I need to be able to either detect and set it in the DbContext, or in override it in code in the Controller...

Comment: Your startup code doesn't run under a 'domain'. It runs when the application starts. You will never have a `HttpContext` in Startup, because it doesn't run within the context of a request. The code above adds `DbContextOptions` as a `scoped` service, meaning it will be constructed for each separate request.

Comment: I didn't try it as it can't work for me - as you point out, I can't get the httpcontext here, so there is no logic to determine the connection string I can enter. Unless I misunderstood you?

Comment: Yes, you misunderstand. If you had tried, you would have probably seen that the code within `services.AddScoped` actually runs within the context of a HTTP request. It does not run at startup, it is only registered at startup. So yes, this method actually does have `HttpContext` available. Please don't discard answers without even trying, it discourages people from helping you in the future. You probably should read a bit more about [DI in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: Apologies. I did indeed brush over this without due care and your method works perfectly. I was in a rush at the time, no excuse, but thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpContextAccessor` is no longer wired up by default.
Make sure you add the service in your `ConfigureServices` method. That way you'll be able to use the HttpCOntext inside your DbContext classes.

Your DbContext as posted in this question would be fine.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     ...
     services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer());
     services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I can access the HttpContextAccessor in a Controller, but not in the DbContext file... In the code in the question I show the various ways I have tried to inject/access it in the DbContext, but none of them actually inject it or allow it to be accessed in the onconfigure method.

Comment: Is your DbContext added as a singleton perhaps? This should work if it is scoped.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Can you give an example code line(s) of what you mean?